# How to differentiate focus event between page-load and manual?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, datepicker, focus

If anyone can come up with a better title, please edit.

I have a web form and the first field is a datepicker. I'm using jQuery-UI's datepicker, which means that whenever the textbox gets focus, the datepicker shows. Unfortunately, since this is the first element on the form, the textbox gets focus immediately on page load, and the datepicker opens without the user doing anything. Oh, and it also covers some other form fields that come next.

I could come up with a fix for this if I could only distinguish what caused that first focus event. Any ideas about it?

Comment: may be just attach `autofocus` attribute on some other element?

Comment: @Cherniv - Yes, or I could arrange the fields differently. That's a good fallback if I cannot get it to work otherwise.

Comment: so check a `relatedTarget` of your `FocusEvent` : http://jsfiddle.net/wsbF6/1/

Comment: @Cherniv - Doesn't work for me. No matter which browser I try, `relatedTarget` stays `null` or `undefined` for me.

Answer (score 0):

> if I could only distinguish what caused that first focus event.

No you can't.

If tab-order is not important for your form just set tabIndex of datePicker's input to negative value.